# Extracting the last line of a multiline string inside a list

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

So, I have the following problem:

I have the following code blocks that I made in Google Colab. This one bellow creates lists with the paths for the files

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/classes"
list_qrels = []
list_results = []

for i in range (len(list_of_classes)):
  list_qrels.append(f"{path}/{list_of_classes[i]}/qrel{list_of_classes[i]}_N.txt")
  list_results.append(f"{path}/{list_of_classes[i]}/results{list_of_classes[i]}_N.txt")
```

Then, using these lists, I use them to execute trec_eval and the outputs for each evaluation measure are stored in a list

```py
list_p = []
list_r = []
list_map = []
list_ndcg = []
measures = ["set_P", "set_recall", "map", "ndcg"]

for i in range (len(measures)):
  for j in range (len(list_of_classes)):
    cmd = os.popen(f"./trec_eval -q -m {measures[i]} {list_qrels[j]} {list_results[j]}").read()
    if measures[i] == "set_P":
      list_p.append(cmd)
    elif measures[i] == "set_recall":
      list_r.append(cmd)
    elif measures[i] == "map":
      list_map.append(cmd)
    elif measures[i] == "ndcg":
      list_ndcg.append(cmd)
```

Then I change some text around within the output strings so that it's easier to interpret

```py
import re
things = ['\t', ' +']
for x in range(len(things)):
  for n in range(len(list_of_classes)):
    list_p[n] = re.sub(things[x], ' ', list_p[n])
    list_p[n] = re.sub('set_P', 'P', list_p[n])

    list_r[n] = re.sub(things[x], ' ', list_r[n])
    list_r[n] = re.sub('set_recall', 'R', list_r[n])

    list_map[n] = re.sub(things[x], ' ', list_map[n])
    list_map[n] = re.sub('map', 'MAP', list_map[n])

    list_ndcg[n] = re.sub(things[x], ' ', list_ndcg[n])
    list_ndcg[n] = re.sub('ndcg', 'NDCG', list_ndcg[n])
```

My problem is: I want to only keep the last line of the strings within the measure lists but, when I try to use `splitlines`, it creates several lists within the list.

Any help is helpful :)

All code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1282xVJHFwQBM48fnaq7RkKCj4NEyfUgS#scrollTo=pgN9WgdZtKpa

Comment: `something.splitlines()[-1]` will be the last line in `something`

Comment: P.S. Please learn to use `for element in list:` instead of `for index in range(len(list)):`